# Inheritance dubt with implementation

Tags: inheritance, interface, uml, implementation

I' m a software engineering student and I'm trying to implements a simple system as in pic

[image]
I would know if this kind of realization can be correct.

Expecially interface A inherit from interface IA1 and IA2 because they represent different *users* of system whit different rights.

In addition B is their boss! :) He has the same (and more) rights.

Answer (score 0):

In general it could be a working solution that fits the needs of your excercise. A small point on the "notes" you make in <<..>>,

1. you dont need them at the relations you are using,
2. in UML terminology it is called generalization/specialization instead of inheritence and realization instead of implementation. One time you use implements with capital and one time without.

Depending on what you are trying to describe (it is not clear, as the question is not precise enough) there might be something missing.

Comment: I agree with what you said. But your last sentence is not specific. Does it mean "there might be" instead of "there is"?